Unity 6 ScoreText and experience doesn't work / Update
using UnityEngine;
using TMPro;

public class ScoreManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public ScoreManager scoreManager;
    public int score = 0; // Player's score
    public TextMeshProUGUI scoreText; // Reference to the TextMeshPro text component

    // Method to add points
    public void AddPoints(int points)
    {
        score += points;
        Debug.Log("Added points: " + points + ", New Score: " + score); // Debug-Log hinzufügen
        UpdateScoreText();
    }

    // Method to update the score display
    private void UpdateScoreText()
    {
        scoreText.text = score.ToString();
    }
}

using UnityEngine;

public class Enemy : MonoBehaviour
{
    private int currentHealth; // Current health of the enemy
    private ScoreManager scoreManager;
    private Transform playerTransform; // Reference to the player's transform
    private int expAmount;

    public EnemyData enemyData; // Reference to the ScriptableObject

    private Animator anim;
    public EnemyManager enemyManager; // Reference to the EnemyManager

    public static CountdownSlider instance;
    public ExperienceManager experienceManager;  // Reference to ExperienceManager

    private void Start()
    {
        anim = GetComponent<Animator>(); // Get Animator component
    }

    // Initialize method to set references
    public void Initialize(ScoreManager scoreManager, EnemyManager enemyManager, Transform player, ExperienceManager experienceManager)
    {
        this.scoreManager = scoreManager; // Set the reference to ScoreManager
        this.enemyManager = enemyManager; // Set the reference to EnemyManager
        this.experienceManager = experienceManager; // Corrected this line
        this.playerTransform = player; // Set the player reference
        currentHealth = enemyData.health; // Initialize current health
        expAmount = enemyData.expAmount;
    }

    public void Die()
    {
        if (enemyData = null)
        {
            if (scoreManager = null)
            {
                scoreManager.AddPoints(enemyData.pointsOnDeath);
            }

            if (experienceManager = null)
            {
                experienceManager.AddExperience(expAmount);
            }

            DropItems();
        }

        if (enemyManager != null)
        {
            enemyManager.RemoveEnemy(this);
        }

        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
}

using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using TMPro;

public class ExperienceManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static ExperienceManager Instance;
    [Header("Experience")]
    [SerializeField] AnimationCurve experienceCurve;

    int currentLevel, totalExperience;
    int previousLevelsExperience, nextLevelsExperience;

    [Header("Interface")]
    [SerializeField] TextMeshProUGUI levelText;
    [SerializeField] TextMeshProUGUI experienceText;
    [SerializeField] Image experienceFill;

    void Start()
    {
        UpdateLevel();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        // Removed the AddExperience call from Update
    }

    public void AddExperience(int amount)
    {
        totalExperience += amount;
        CheckForLevelUp();
        UpdateInterface();
    }

    void CheckForLevelUp()
    {
        if (totalExperience >= nextLevelsExperience)
        {
            currentLevel++;
            UpdateLevel();
            // Start level up sequence... Possibly vfx?
        }
    }

    void UpdateLevel()
    {
        previousLevelsExperience = (int)experienceCurve.Evaluate(currentLevel);
        nextLevelsExperience = (int)experienceCurve.Evaluate(currentLevel + 1);
        UpdateInterface();
    }

    void UpdateInterface()
    {
        int start = totalExperience - previousLevelsExperience;
        int end = nextLevelsExperience - previousLevelsExperience;

        levelText.text = currentLevel.ToString();
        experienceText.text = start + " exp / " + end + " exp";
        experienceFill.fillAmount = (float)start / (float)end;
    }
}

using UnityEngine;

[CreateAssetMenu(fileName = "NewEnemyData", menuName = "Enemy Data")]
public class EnemyData : ScriptableObject
{
    public GameObject enemyPrefab; // Prefab des Gegners
    public int health; // Gesundheit des Gegners
    public float speed; // Bewegungsgeschwindigkeit des Gegners
    public int pointsOnDeath; // Punkte, die der Spieler erhält, wenn der Gegner stirbt
    public GameObject[] dropItems; // Items, die der Gegner fallen lässt
    public float spawnChance; // Wahrscheinlichkeit, dass dieser Gegner spawnt
    public int damage; // Schaden, den dieser Gegner verursacht
    public int expAmount; // Erfahrungspunkte die ein Gegner gibt.
}

Unfortunately I don't know why the text doesn't update. In unity I have no errors and all references are set correctly. I'm really starting to despair. I've tried so many things but without any error messages it's difficult for a beginner to understand what the problem could be.
I try blackbox.ai youtube google

A lot of times, why its not working boils down to some simple debug statements.  So, in your code, the score only changes on Die(), and I dont see anything calling Die(), but on top of that it must have a reference to EnemyData, and the scoremanager for it to update it, so the text must be enabled, the score manager must be set, the thing that calls Die() must be active, so on, so put debug messages in to find out what gets called and  what it has when it gets there..

I needed to Cut the Code Die() is here
public void TakeDamage(int damageAmount)
{
    currentHealth -= damageAmount;

    // Check if health is less than or equal to 0
    if (currentHealth <= 0)
    {
        Die();
    }
    else
    {
        // Trigger hit animation
        anim.SetTrigger("hit"); // Ensure this trigger is correctly set in the Animator
    }
}

